# Is there a way to make people not feel as bad when they contribute to this network?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

Some stack exchange users might not like feeling like they've done something wrong on Stack Exchange and can't doing anything without wondering if they're going to do something wrong and hate that. Maybe there's a way for people to teach them by writing comments without making them feel that way. For example, giving somebody an indefinite question ban might not be worth it because it might make them feel that way even if it's better for the network and instead, after they've been shown to be asking a lot of not very good questions, just get a 21 day question limit and after they ask another question after they get a chance, get a 21 day question limit again and if the question turns out to be good, have the limit end sooner. Also, we can never be sure they aren't going to learn how to ask more good questions than bad questions. Maybe they could also be told that  nobody has an obligation to contribute to the network so it's not that bad to have been made unable to by a block and they didn't do anything wrong but other hard workers did the hard work for them of figuring out how to decide when to block so that they will worry less about making sure they don't write any inaccurate answers because they can get blocked preventing more of them. For me personally, I think it would be better if it worked in such a way that when I'm at my question limit, the probability density of my limit ending remains constant at 1/21 days and I didn't find out when it was going to end until after it ends because that way, I'll see that my experience is all the same to me regardless of how soon my limit is going to end and learn how to enjoy the time before my limit ends and focus on the fact that a goal I previously set of asking another question and seeing if it ends up good has already been done instead of impatiently waiting for it to end and if it's a fixed 21 days and every time I ask a question, I reach my limit, then I will set a new goal of that limit ending and by the time I'm near the end of my life which is probably more than 50 years away, I won't be ready to die before my goal gets done.

For people who are frequently sometimes giving answer with wrong information, maybe they could get an indefinite ban but still have the ability to post a pending answer, and other people could waste less time by marking ones they're not sure are worth keeping as undecided than by blocking them from writing a pending answer in the first place because they insist on doing the research to not reject one that's worthy of keeping, but once in a while, they could review a pending answer of theirs more carefully and approve it if it's worthy of keeping. However for any user, probably very little of any information they ever learned they know for certain is true and it's not worth them write so few answers in the first place because of that. For that reason, researchers themselves should decide it's their job to do their own research and not be so sure that information they read in a Stack Exchange answer or information they got from a web page after Googling is true just because that web page said so when they can't verify another way that it's true.

Also, I find it annoying that I don't get notified when an answer or question I wrote gets deleted. It means me slower to learn whether a question or answer I wrote belongs. Also, if somebody tries to help me learn my writing a comment to a question or answer I wrote and then I don't check Stack Exchange after it gets written and before my question or answer gets deleted, I might miss seeing the comment. If I at least got notified that a question or answer I wrote got deleted, then I could go to the question page and see if a comment was written on it. Also, nobody can teach somebody else a method that tells them how to figure out for certain whether a question or answer is fine to write in a certain way so maybe when somebody tries to teach somebody else by writing a comment, they could be aware that they're just saying what's probably true and not what they know is true and the person they wrote to is free to write back and discuss why they think it might not be true. For me, being given that type of comment is better than being given no comment. Also, they could write a comment and be clear that it is a suggestion and not an order and the person is just meant to do their best so that the other person can make an effort to improve the site by the way they write questions and answer but not feel guilt for not doing a better job of it than they can and instead be like "Seven" from the movie "Gifted" who got interested in solving the "Navier-Stokes existence and smoothness" problem but didn't get stressed over wondering if she couldn't do it.

Comment: This really needs some formatting. It's quite difficult to read.

Comment: That is quite a wall of text, it would be better if you could make a concise point, as it stands I have no idea the point you are trying to make as you ramble so much.

Comment: _"Maybe there's a way for people to teach them by writing comments without making them feel that way. "_ No one likes being patronized.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  You say that, and yet people *very* consistently get upset whenever people have high (or, honestly, just not super low) expectations of people asking questions.  Assuming people are able to do a web search for their question, look at the documentation for something they're asking about, etc. are consistently stated as being unreasonable expectations of people asking question.  I consider having such low expectations of people to be insulting to them, like you seem to as well.  I just think we're in smaller company that we'd like to be.

Comment: At the end of the day, posting here is a privilege, not a right.  You only get banned once the system is confident the user cannot contribute in a meaningful fashion.  And they get many warnings along the way.  Ignore them at your own peril.

Comment: Honestly, I never really made it past the first sentence. This needs some better formatting. You seem to be saying multiple things that aren't necessarily related to the summary of your question.

Comment: @MarkKirby Some people probably have a really good memory and smartness and people sometimes ask a question that's understandable to one of them but can't be written in a way that's understandable to very many more people. Maybe one of them is good at answering questions that are hard to read like this one. Also, it would be nice to know the probable reason this question got 12 downvotes.

Comment: I can’t even read the whole question cause it is like Text Overflow (corny joke). But like some other comments note, you should really try to shorten it a bit. Just keep the most important parts.

Comment: Just read the comments, and I think that the probable reason for the downvotes is how much text there is and also the needed formatting edits to make it a little easier to read. @Timothy

Comment: 21 days?  That would mean a bad user would only need three accounts to post one 'Sunday homework dump' a week:(

Comment: Well, perhaps I am just too dumb to understand but the -22 score says I am not alone in not been able to understand your point. I did not downvote this but I think from other comments, people voted for the same reasons.

Comment: I swear. I only have 1 Stack Exchange account.

Comment: Just had a chance to read the post in its entirety. Talk about run on sentences...one of the formatting edits needs to improve that.

Comment: @LAD I was going to edit/format it, but it's so long that I suspected that someone else would be making the same effort in parallel, so I didn't bother.  End result - nobody bothered, probably all for the same reason:(

Comment: @MartinJames I have edited some very long posts on SO before, but I have found that it isn't really worth spending a half hour editing a post that the OP should edit himself and then there is the chance that your edit doesn't even count.

Comment: Also, if I were to edit the post, I feel like I would have to reword quite a bit or take out some parts, and that would probably be to the OP's discontent.

Comment: @LAD By OP, do you mean the original asker of this question which is me? I'd be fine with you editing this question to make it better except it already has an answer and according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288467/should-i-make-major-edits-to-a-question/288471#288471, questions with an answer aren't supposed to be edited because it could invalidate the answer. Do you think it should be possible for somebody to write a question then close it to make sure it doesn't get answered before it's improved. Maybe I could ask why questions are closed then close that question.

Comment: @Timothy By editing your post, I don't mean changing the meaning of it, just making it easier to read by editing the grammar and size of it. It should be quite possible to make the post shorter by taking out parts that aren't as important to the overall message, or at least phrasing things more concisely. For this post, though, it probably doesn't matter if it gets edited at this point, so my suggestions are for any future posts that you might write. As for your other question, only users with moderator tools can have a question put on hold. And yes, OP means original poster.

Answer (score 21):

People that are getting post banned are people that have consistently and repeatedly made serious mistakes.  They've done so despite repeated warnings that their behavior is problematic, and with no improvements.  They're users that have so consistently been of net harm to the site that *we don't want them participating anymore* because they're just so unlikely to provide a useful contribution.

Honestly, if someone feels *good* after doing all of that *then something is very wrong with the system*.  Being *that* bad shouldn't make you feel good.  We also don't want to keep trying to incentivise them to post more and more content, in very short time periods, as you propose, or to add significant burdens to other members of the site to allow them to continue posting content.  *They have shown that they are not going to produce useful content if they were allowed to do that*.

There are ways of coming back from a post ban, but they are hard.  They're hard *by design*, because the only way such a user can be trusted to post normally again is to really put in the time and effort to demonstrate that they understand the rules now, and they're willing to put the time and effort needed to ask *quality* question (or post quality answers, as the case may be).

Comment: But I think we should also be careful that when somebody's doing their best, they aren't made to feel awful that their best isn't good enough.

Comment: @Timothy When people are getting post banned you can be fairly confident that they're not doing their best.   You need to be doing *really* bad to get post banned.  Odds are very high that they're not putting forth anywhere near the level of time that they should be into their posts.  Additionally, you need to consider all of the feelings of all of the people that are being harmed by people posting problematic content.  Why should *they* continually be made to feel awful because you're unwilling to tell someone that they're doing something wrong when their behavior is harming others?

Comment: I feel like I didn't understand what I was doing wrong before I got blocked from asking questions on Mathematics Stack Exchange. I think that in order for researchers to be really good researchers, there would be very few facts they claim to know are true but they would still speed up research by using facts they state are probably true with a reason that other people can refute. I later got unblocked and asked one more question and got blocked again. I thought it seemed better than the questions I was asking before but I'm glad I got another chance.

Comment: Do you mean most users want other users to be honest and tell them when they're harming the site?

Comment: @Timothy The point that's getting made is that bad content harms those that have to read it.  That's why the post ban exists; so that when someone has demonstrated their inability to meet the high standards of the network, their privilege to post is removed.  They also get many warnings along the way.  If they refuse to read it and help themselves, well, they're showing exactly why their posting privileges are being removed.

Comment: @Timothy If you were post banned (and even if you weren't) then you were given *lots* of information on what is expected of you as a question author, and also information on what you were doing that was wrong.  You're not *allowed* to ask a question without being shown advice on how to ask appropriate questions and what is expected of you.  That you were given a chance to ask a question after being post banned and squandered it.  That's not an example that supports giving people more chances.  It's evidence that it would be a *bad* idea.

Comment: 5 of my questions on Mathematics Stack Exchange ended up being good questions despite the fact that I have no experience doing a research job. There's never a zero chance that my next question will be a good one. If only I could prove I don't have more than one network of linked Stack Exchange accounts on different sites, then after enough time, it would be worth giving me one more chance. I might eventually get to the point where more than half the time I ask a question, its' a good question. It's worse to risk writing a horrible answer than a horrible question.

Comment: @Timothy You have five questions that aren't so bad you've deleted them.  Of those, two have a score of 0, one has a score of +1 *but is closed for being off topic*, one only has a score of 2, which is okay but not spectacular, leaving only one question that is actually notably well received.  Your odds of a question being good may not be zero, but they're *very, very* low.  All of those bad questions have a cost, and can't just be ignored because there's a minuscule chance that you'll ask a good question.

Comment: @Servy I'm sometimes writing answers on Mathematics Stack Excahnge but I think I'm making sure I never write ones with wrong information but am not making sure all of them belong because otherwise, I couldn't write any and other people can delete the ones that don't belong and ones that are so much work to research whether they belong. I think that a lot of times AsafKaragila is writing comments on my answers to try to teach me but then the question gets deleted and I don't even get notified of the comment or its deletion and that's so annoying. Maybe somebody should ask about that.

Comment: @Timothy You shouldn't be doing that.  Don't just ask questions that don't belong and expect other people to clean up after you.  That's exactly the type of behavior these tools are designed to prevent.  If you want to be allowed to ask questions, take the time to ensure that your questions are appropriate before posting them, rather than just expecting others to deal with your problems for you.

Comment: @Servy I'm not asking any at this moment. I only have a question ban and not an answer ban. What am I supposed to do, never write any answers at all and never contribute to Mathematics Stack Exchange at all because I have a question ban and never learn how to be a person who makes an overall positive contribution to that site. Maybe I could get a good memory and some time, not forget the title of any question I wrote an answer to after that time and then later go to that question to see if my answer was deleted or if AsafKaragila wrote a comment on it.

Comment: @Timothy Waiting until after you've posted so many bad posts that you had to be banned to *start* trying to figure out how to post properly is precisely the problem.  You should have taken the time to figure out how to post properly *before* you started posting, or at a bare minimum, worked to improve your posts when they were received poorly and you were told that you were on your way to getting banned.  You were the one who choose to ignore those warnings.